# i have render my animation in png form but after rendering is showing a flie which cant be open

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

i have render but it has came in a file format

Comment: If you're saving an animation and have png format selected you should have one png file for each frame of your animation not a single file! Are you sure that the save path is correct on that panel? Click the folder icon and see where it's pointing.